Nested urllib.parse unquote usage
I am trying to unquote a URL-encoded string that comes from AWS access log while auditing hive partitioned table activity (partition is /ymd=yyyymmdd). Content in S3 access log is of format: "mr_test/mr_test_6/ymd%253D20210105/000001_0"
I used 2-levels of nested calls to unquote() to work properly, I have seen a couple of other examples of this usage on this site - is this the right way to do it?
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> unquote("mr_test/mr_test_6/ymd%253D20210105/000001_0")          # works partially
'mr_test/mr_test_6/ymd%3D20210105/000001_0'
>>> unquote(unquote("mr_test/mr_test_6/ymd%253D20210105/000001_0")) # works fully
'mr_test/mr_test_6/ymd=20210105/000001_0'

